# OneLogin POST binding support for AuthnRequest

Tags: saml, onelogin

I hope you are doing well,
I wanna ask about is there a way to make my authnrequest to support POST Binding or its impossible.

thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide many details but yes onelogin seems to support urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST for SingleSignOnService

The question is whether your SAML2 libary supports it for you Service Provider.